# When i press power on my ps3 fat model the light turns green then yellow then it starts blinking red with no further results

Tags: ps3

When i press power on my ps3 fat model the light turns green then yellow then it starts blinking red with no further results. I tried the eject method of holding down the eject button while turning on and off the power and then the fan comes on really hard and the green light stays on for about a minute then goes back to red blinking.i tried all the reset methods but once it goes back to blinking red it will only turn off but i dont get the three beeps after holding power for about a minute

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in this [PS3 support forum post](https://community.eu.playstation.com/t5/PS3-Support/What-do-the-different-light-colours-on-the-PlayStation-3-mean/td-p/13381892), the blinking red light means that the console has shut down because of overheating.

It is suggested to make sure that your vents are not blocked free of dust (be careful when using a vaccum cleaner here - don't let the fans turn freely as they induce a voltage that may kill components on the mainboard). You already booted the console up in the fan-clearing mode (what you described as "eject method") - maybe try to do that a couple times more to blow the vents and fans free. Then let the console cool down for a while before trying again.

If it keeps happening you will probably have to give into servicing. Since this behaviour is a common sign of a near yellow light of death ("YLOD") which corresponds to a hardware failure (e.g. cold soldering spots on mainboard), you can also try to follow this [iFixit repair article](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Yellow+Light+of+Death+Repair/3654).

It seems to be non-trivial, even for a tech-savvy person. I haven't tried that myself, so I can't give further advice on this.